# Css transition thumbnail scroll

Tags: javascript, html, css, transform

I am trying to make thumbnail scroll with css transitions. My goal is to wrap the content when it comes to an end.

```
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="inner">
    <div class="box">0</div>
    <div class="box">1</div>
    <div class="box">2</div>
    <div class="box">3</div>
    <div class="box">4</div>
    <div class="box">5</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

I have made a mockup on jsfiddle. It works well first 3 clicks, but then it stops animating (when it enters if condition to move first box to an end).

https://jsfiddle.net/aqwaypoh/

Why does it loose animation afterwards and how to fix it?

Thanks!

Comment: What do you mean by _wrap the content_

Comment: use move button and see that happens with boxes (look at numbers). As they move left when they come to an end on right side, boxes from far left go the the right.